# Solving PDE $v_t(t,x) + \frac{1}{2} v_{xx} (t,x) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

We are given a PDE with 
$$v_t(t,x) + \frac{1}{2} v_{xx} (t,x) = 0$$
$$ v(T,x) = x^2 $$
for $0 < t \leq T$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$

So far I have found that using the Feynmann-Kac equation, we get
$$
v_t + \frac{1}{2} (2 W_t)^2 v_{xx} = 0
$$
using the fact that $dX_t = 2W_t dW_t$ for $X_t = W_t^2 - t$.

So, I come up with an answer
$$
v(x,t) = -2W_t^2 t + x^2
$$
which doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Since you have a *final* condition $v(T,x)=x^2$ instead of an initial condition, and you would like to solve the problem *backwards*, for the time interval $t \in (0,T)$, it is very useful to reverse time, that is, to introduce $\tau = T- t$, such that the equation becomes
\begin{equation}
 v_{\tau} = \frac{1}{2} v_{xx},\qquad v(\tau=0,x) = x^2
\end{equation}
for $0\leq \tau < T$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This is the *heat equation*; to solve it, read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Homogeneous_heat_equation).